# Using Google apps script apply "go to sections based on answer" on Google Form ERROR Message : list.createChoice is not a function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am using FORM RANGER to auto-populate data, but once it populate,Multiple choice go to sections based on answer always erase.
I am trying use GAS to keep branching while this FORM open, but ERROR message "list.createChoice is not a function".
I've read similar question before and working with this problem about 2 days but still can't figure it out......
Following is my code, wish someone can help me, thank you!

```
    function GoToPage() {
        var form = FormApp.openById('');

        var list = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE);
        var list1 = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE)[0].asMultipleChoiceItem().getChoices().map(choice => choice.getValue());
        var choice1 = list1[0];
        var choice2 = list1[1];
        var choice3 = list1[2];

        var pagelist = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK);
        var pagebreak01 = pagelist[2].asPageBreakItem();
        var pagebreak02 = pagelist[3].asPageBreakItem();
        var pagebreak03 = pagelist[4].asPageBreakItem();

        var choices = [];
        choices.push(list1.createChoice(choice1,pagebreak01));
        choices.push(list1.createChoice(choice2,pagebreak02)); 
        choices.push(list1.createChoice(choice3,pagebreak03));
        list.setChoices(choices);
    }
```

Addition:
I have four multiple choices, auto-populated by FORM RANGER from spreadsheet,and set four choices go to four sections one by one.

Once I execute, it shows:
「TypeError: list1.createChoice is not a function
GoToPage
@ GOTOSEC.gs:16」

I thought this error might because input variables can't fit with "createChoice" function, but I read a lot of previous post and tried many times with other syntax,still can't work :(

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add the textual error message.

Comment: The error message is "「TypeError: list1.createChoice is not a function GoToPage @ GOTOSEC.gs:16」",thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved it with Rubén's solution, and substitute this kind of syntax:

```
choices.push(list1.createChoice(choice,pagebreak));
```

To this:

```
choices.push(list.asMultipleChoiceItem().createChoice(list1[i], pagebreak));
```

Comment: And laterly, I abandoned FORM RANGER because of some populate corrupted, instead of using pure code to apply populate. It's more efficient than some trash to refresh form.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the third line,

```
var list = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE);
```

returns a Array. Assuming that you want to modify the first multiple choice question, replace this line by

```
var list = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE)[0];
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, I've tried this way and also try change "list1.createChoice" to "list.createChoice" , but still show the same message .